# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr ERROR in 12-column bmatrix

Tags: columns, alignment

That's in a chapter of my thesis template so I dont need \begin{document}. So in this chapter I wanna make a 12-column `bmatrix` inside this equation like this:

[image]

and thats the code im trying to form it:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\left[N\right]
=
\begin{bmatrix}
N_1 & 0 & 0 & N_2 & 0 & 0 & N_3 & 0 & 0 & N_4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & N_1 & 0 & 0 & N_2 & 0 & 0 & N_3 & 0 & 0 & N_4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & N_1 & 0 & 0 & N_2 & 0 & 0 & N_3 & 0 & 0 & N_4
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
```

but I get this error:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

at the 3 lines after `\begin{bmatrix}` and I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: By default `bmatrix` only handles up to 10 cols, add `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}` to your preamble.

Comment: thank you it worked